# What kind of file is this?

Tags: files

I've ran `file myfile` and got the following:

```
MSVC .sbr H\002I
```

Any advice on what this particular file could be?

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2007/12/18/intellisense-history-part-1/

Answer (score 1):

Is a Microsoft Visual Studio Visual C++ source browser intermediate file.

Look [here](https://www.file-extensions.org/sbr-file-extension) and [here](http://dotwhat.net/file/extension/sbr/835) to know how to open it.